# C# WinForms Online Publishing and URL Parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i need some information about C# WinForms.

I search an Documentation or some first Step Tips for passing URL Parameters to WinForm Applications.

When i publish a WinForms Application in Visual Studio in just online Mode (Publish > Installationmode and configuration > Just online)

[VS - Just Online (German)](http://share.srg-rv.de/pubjuston.png)

In the Options Dialog in the Manifest Section is an Checkbox to allow passing URL Prameters to the application.

[VS - Allow URL Parameters (sorry, German again)](http://share.srg-rv.de/puburlpars.png)

My Question is how to pass and grab those Parameters in the Application.

Normaly i found what i Need with Google .... but this time i dont even what to search for.

And sorry but i'm not the native english Speaker/writer, and i use the germen Visual Studio so i'm not sure if the Options mentioned above are correctly spelled ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query` is what you are looking for.

[Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx) from Microsoft:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Deployment.Application;
...
private NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
{
    NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }
    return (nameValueTable);
}
```

In the link above it is also described how you pass those parameters:

> The query string is the portion of a URL beginning with a question mark (?) that contains arbitrary information in the form name=value. Suppose you have a ClickOnce application named WindowsApp1 that you host on servername, and you want to pass in a value for the variable username when the application launches. Your URL might look like the following:
>   http://servername/WindowsApp1.application?username=joeuser

Comment: Perfect, thats the documentation i was looking for, thumbs up. Just for my personal freedom: how did you search for this documentation? i spended hours and dont find anythig

Comment: I just searched for 'Visual Studio publishing url parameters' in google, second entry =)